# In Rails, why does assign_attributes doesn't assign in two nested levels (or more) children models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, assign

In rails, I have :

- a projet that has many immeubles
- a immeuble has many logements
- a logement has a work
- a logement has a devis_logements
- a devis_logement has a devis
- a devis_logement has a logement

In my controller, I define :

```rb
def save_montage_projet
  @projet_courant = Projet.find(params[:projet_id]
  @projet_courant.assign_attributes(save_montage_params)
end
```

where save_montage_params equals :

```rb
def save_montage_params
  params.require(:projet).permit(:id, 
               immeubles_attributes: [:id, :projet_id, :annee_achevement, :version,
               logements_attributes: [:id, :immeuble_id, :logement_loue, 
                                      work_attributes: [:theme], 
                                      devis_logements_attributes: [:id, :logement_id, :devis_id]]])
end
```

When `annee_achevement` is changed, the `@projet_courant.immeubles.find_by(version: 'montage')` and `@projet_courant.immeubles.find_by(version: 'montage').pb_logements.first`  have the correct parameters assigned.

However, when `annee_achevement` is not changed, the `@projet_courant.immeubles.find_by(version: 'montage')` and `@projet_courant.immeubles.find_by(version: 'montage').pb_logements.first`  no longer have any parameters assigned.

Here's my nested form:

```
= form_with model: @projet_courant, url: save_montage_projet_path(@projet_courant), method: 'post' do |projet_form|
    = projet_form.hidden_field :id
    - immeuble = @projet_courant.immeubles.find_by(version: 'montage')
    = projet_form.fields_for :immeubles, immeuble do |immeuble_form|
        = immeuble_form.hidden_field :id
        = immeuble_form.hidden_field :projet_id
        = immeuble_form.fields_for :logements do |logement_form|
          = logement_form.hidden_field :id
          = logement_form.hidden_field :immeuble_id
          = logement_form.hidden_field :projet_id, value: @projet_courant.id

          = immeuble_form.text_field :annee_achevement
          = immeuble_form.text_field :version

          = logement_form.text_field :logement_loue
          = logement_form.fields_for :work do |work_form|
            = work_form.text_field :theme
          = logement_form.fields_for :devis_logement do |work_form|
            = work_form.hidden_field :logement_id
            = work_form.hidden_field :projet_id
```

My params in both cases are the same.